# Shape of urea molecule around N atom

Tags: molecular-structure, crystal-structure, vsepr-theory

I was doing a question where I was supposed to predict the shape of the urea molecule $[\ce{H2N(CO)NH2}]$ using Lewis and VSEPR. I identified that the N atoms will have a lone pair on them and so I assigned a trigonal pyramidal shape around N, having the ammonia structure in mind. However when I looked up some 3D structures of the urea molecule it had a trigonal planar shape around N making the whole molecule lie in the same plane. I did some further research and read on wikipedia that

"The urea molecule is planar in the crystal structure, but the geometry around the nitrogens is pyramidal in the gas-phase minimum-energy structure."

What causes this change in geometry when the molecule crystallizes? Does the same thing go for other molecules? Would there have been a way of predicting this as I was solving the question?

Comment: Its an interesting question and I would enjoy seeing an answer, but I doubt it possible to predict that change in geometry beforehand. The structure around N in the crystal would depend a lot on the packing together of molecules of urea, and I don't think you could get a good sense of that at the level of VSEPR. Also, I see you are new to the site. If you haven't yet, take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Welcome to chem SE! @Louloulelle

Answer (score 5):

> I was supposed to predict the shape of the urea molecule $[\ce{H2N(CO)NH2}]$ using Lewis and **VSEPR**.

Don't forget that there are assumptions in VSPER to simplify the model. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory):

> Valence shell electron pair repulsion (VSEPR) theory is a model used in chemistry to predict the geometry of **individual molecules**...

Essentially VSPER is for molecules in the gas phase where the only electrostatic interactions are within the molecule. Once the molecule is in a condensed phase, the assumption that it does not interact with external forces breaks down.

> What causes this change in geometry when the molecule crystallizes?

For one let's not forget that urea is a resonant structure, and does not have fixed bonds which also goes against assumptions of VSPER.

[image: resonance structure of urea]

Further you have neighboring molecules with the hydrogens of those molecule taking some electron density from the resonance structure which is shown in the unit cell representation shown below:

[image]

In summary you have resonance which will flatten out the molecule and other molecules taking some electron density that combined will contribute further causing the molecule to flatten out.

> Does the same thing go for other molecules?

Yes, other molecules can condense and form structures that deviate from VSPER. [Water in ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Ih) for example has a $109.5 ^\circ$ bond angle (tetrahedral angle) where as VSPER would predict $104.5^\circ$ (bent angle).

> Would there have been a way of predicting this as I was solving the question?

No, you would have to know how urea crystallizes and many other factors, then used a computer simulation to calculate (estimate) such.